# How to retrieve data from multiple Google Analytics accounts using Google API?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have a web application that gives its users the option to grant it offline access to the user's Google Analytics account. The problem I run into is that when I need to output data from multiple Google Analytics accounts at once. When I update the access token for each user and attempt to retrieve data, I always receive the data from the first access token stored.

Below is example PHP code that loops through 2 refresh tokens, creates and sets access tokens for each and pulls the profile IDs that each user has access to. Since I reset the access token in the loop, I would expect it to output the profiles that each user has access to, but instead, it outputs the profiles that the first user has access to twice. Similarly, if I change the loop to start with the second refresh token, the profiles that the second user as access to is printed twice:

```
$refresh_token1 = "123";
$refresh_token2 = "456";

foreach(array($refresh_token1,$refresh_token2) as $r){
    $access_token = array( "access_token" => "", "token_type" => "Bearer", "expires_in" => 0, "refresh_token" => $r, "created" => 0 );
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
    $obj = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles('~all', '~all');
    if (count($obj->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $obj->getItems();
        foreach($items as $item){
            echo $item->getId()."<BR>";
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried calling the "$client->refreshToken($r)" command after the first loop, but that doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: make sure you are updating the refresh token in the client as well.  The client library will automatically grab you a new access token if its needed using the refresh token it has.

Comment: @DaImTo, isn't that what the $client->setAccessToken($access_token) call does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the access token is not enough. A new client needs to be created in the loop to pull unique data for each user. Here is an updated version of the code that will work:

```
$refresh_token1 = "123";
$refresh_token2 = "456";

foreach(array($refresh_token1,$refresh_token2) as $r){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

    $access_token = array( "access_token" => "", "token_type" => "Bearer", "expires_in" => 0, "refresh_token" => $r, "created" => 0 );
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
    $obj = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles('~all', '~all');
    if (count($obj->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $obj->getItems();
        foreach($items as $item){
            echo $item->getId()."<BR>";
        }
    }
}
```